# Copy a cell value to same row cell via Google Apps Scritp

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have the below code wrapped in a function.  what it does right now if it detects that verifier is not empty and status and aptNumber are empty, then it copies that row and appends it to another spreadsheet and then deletes it.

What I would like to do is copy the value for patNumb and paste it in the verifier if the IF condition is met.

Any ideas?

```
let spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      let sourceSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName(delta);
      let sourceRange = sourceSheet.getDataRange();
      let sourceValues = sourceRange.getValues();
  sourceValues.forEach((row, index)=>{
      let aptNumber = row[10]
      let verifier = row[11]
      let status = row[12]
      let patNumb = row[4]
      if (verifier !== '' && status === '' && aptNumber === ''){
          // console.log('PatNumberEntered: ', aptNumber)
          // console.log('VerifierNameEntered: ', verifier)
          // console.log('CopiedRow: ',row)
          console.log(index)
          copyPatNumber(patNumb)
          // sourceSheet.copyTo(patNumb)
          // pendingTarget.appendRow(row)
          // removeDeltaPendingDuplicates()
          // deleteEachRow()
      }

  });

 function copyPatNumber(value){
    console.log(value)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want the `row` to be appended to the target sheet has `patNumb` value on the `verifier` column when condition is met?

You can just equate the index where `verifier` is assigned and overwrite it with the value of `patNumb` before appending the row.

#### Code:

```
Logger.log(row)
row[11] = patNumb;
Logger.log(row)
pendingTarget.appendRow(row)
```

#### Row before and after:

[image: row]

If I misunderstood your question, please provide a sample sheet with sample data and its expected output when the script is executed.